# Yii2 Kartik Gridview Editable not working with pagination

Tags: pagination, yii2, contenteditable, yii2-advanced-app, kartik-v

I am about to show a list of warranties like this. However, when I tried to using pagination, I can not edit things in EditableCoumn like before. The picture also shows the parameters sent. How can I solve this?

Note: this is just a demo, so I set the pagination size is 1. In real life, we have over a million results instead of 2!

Thank you in advance!

[image: editable column not working]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
echo GridView::widget([
    // set pjax to true then you will be able to do that
    // If set to true, the entire GridView widget will be parsed via Pjax and rendered inside a yii\widgets\Pjax widget container
    'pjax' => true, // pjax is set to always true for this demo
]);
```